# get XML format of NSDictionary and send in NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, websocket

I have NSDictionary with BOOL and NSString,

```
 NSString *enteredText = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:enterTextField.text];
 BOOL switchSelected = switchControl.on;

 NSDictionary *dictionaryToSend = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:enteredText, @"text", [NSNumber numberWithBool:switchSelected], @"switch", nil];
```

I need to make them in XML format and then send them through web socket in NSData format, cause SocketRocket library has method:

```
// Send a UTF8 String or Data.
- (void)send:(id)data;
```

I stuck on this question. I found a XMLDictionary library on gitHub but it doesn't help me to solve this question. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is a PITA in Objective C. You're probably going to just have to suck it up and write a function (or series of functions) to just append a string of XML. Something like:

```
- (NSString *)xmlStringFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    NSString *returnString = @"<data>";

    for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
        NSString *value = dictionary[key];
        returnString = [returnString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@>", key, value, key]];
    }

    returnString = [returnString stringByAppendingString:@"</data>"];

    return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this third party library for doing this conversion.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

Comment: I found a XMLDictionary library on gitHub but it doesn't help me to solve this question. How should I do this?

so, how? i tried to understand this library, but i don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [NSPropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSPropertyListFormat) class.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Key":@"Value"};
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&error];
if (!data) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```